# submit form to self

Tags: php, javascript, html

At the moment, I have a form with an input (text) and a button to submit the form.

The form is posted to 'submit.php'. I would like the form posted to same page as the form.

How can I do this?

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="emailField" placeholder="email address" name="email" />
    <button type="submit">
        <div class="submit" />
    </button>
</form>
```

submit.php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', '', '') or die('unable to connect');
    mysql_select_db('') or die('unable to select db');
    $query = mysql_query("");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        exit("You have already subscribed!");
    }
    else {
        mysql_query("") or die(mysql_error());
        exit("You have successfully subscribed!");
    }

?>
```

Comment: What `exit()` method? Is your question missing some code?

Comment: change submit.php to the same page as the form, and check the $_POST to see if the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options here.

### Submit the form onto itself

```
<?php
    if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        // process the form here
    }
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="emailField" placeholder="email address" name="email" />
    <button type="submit">
        <div class="submit" />
    </button>
</form>
```

### Redirect back to the form

Add something like this in `submit.php` where you want to show the form.

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://example.org/form.php');
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: You need to change the extension on that file from `.html` to `.php` so it gets executed as PHP. There are other ways around this but this is the simplest.

Comment: You don't even need to specify action="". Just skip that part all together, since default **is** itself.