# PHP: Store input in .txt file and output to html page

Tags: php, html, text-files

Using PHP I want to store user input from an html page in a .txt file and output that user input onto the same page.

However, nothing is showing up in either the .txt file or on the page div.

**IN ADDITION:** I'd like to have each new message display on a new div, I know this is somewhat of a different question, but I figured it could be related.

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

**HTML:**

The form itself:

```
<textarea name="msg" rows="5"></textarea>
<form id="post" name="post" action="storeText.php" method="post">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="POST!"/>
</form>
```

Where I want to output on the same html page:

```
<div class="menuItem" >
    <?=$msg?>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

storeText.php

```
<?php       
$filename = 'posts.txt';
$msg = (isset($_POST['msg']) ? $_POST['msg'] : null);

    // Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
    if (is_writable($filename)) {

    // In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
    // The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
    // that's where $somecontent will go when we fwrite() it.
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
        echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($handle, $msg) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($msg) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);

    } else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where in your form are you inputting text?

Comment: Woops... that could be my problem... my textarea is outside of the form...

Comment: I updated the html to reflect what it is currently.  I suspect I need to put the textarea inside of the form, correct?

Comment: Where does `$filename` come from?

Comment: Form elements should always be placed inside the `<form></form>` tags. Sometimes it might work as you have it in some browsers, but malformed HTML is not to be relied on.

Comment: And FWIW, instead of the old `fopen` stuff, file_put_contents is a lot easier. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: @Jeffman yeah, I originally did `file_put_contents` but then read somewhere that it's a lot slower...

Comment: If it is (I don't recall) we're talking maybe a millisecond. If you're writing 1000s of files, yeah, look into it. If not, make your life easier.

Comment: If you can't write to the file, check the permissions on your directory and script.

Comment: @Jeffman Well, it's fine on my server because I've used PHP before, but I'm using WAMPServer to test this out... I'll have to figure that one out.

Comment: @Keven Add this just under `$filename = 'posts.txt';` - `chmod($filename, 0644);` or use `0777` may help to solve file writing permissions if that is the case.

Comment: @Keven Give me a few minutes, I'll see what I can do to get this going for you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sure, standing by...

Comment: @Keven Taking more time than I thought. If you still need it later on, I'll polish up what I did. I have to run.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks man.  It's still not working, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: pasting this chat for reference purposes: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/37292

Comment: @Keven Have a look at my answer, best I could do for you. Keep me posted, cheers.

Comment: @Keven Any luck with what I gave you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML markup to the following:

```
<form id="post" name="post" action="storeText.php" method="post">
    <textarea cols="x" rows="x" name="msg"></textarea>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="POST!"/>
</form>
```

You should now be able to write data to the file, provided the file has correct permissions and PHP has write access.

Comment: Guess what.  I'm gonna have to take this check away... editing the if statement broke it...

Comment: I stole this script directly from PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php  Once I changed it back to the way they had it, it worked.

Comment: You answered my original question.  I'll leave the check there.  Well, ALMOST all of it.  I still can't output to the page...

Comment: @AmalMurali I hit submit and the script shows up.  I want the content to load on the same page, but it isn't.

Comment: @Keven: In that case, you could [submit the form to itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381897/submit-form-to-self).

Answer (score 2):

### Give this a try.

There are two files, one for the submission(s) which posts from the same page and the `DIV` include `display_div.php`.

The way it's setup is that it will show the newest post on top.

### PHP handler and form

```
<?php       
// check if the file first exists, if not create the file
if (!file_exists("posts.txt")) {
$fp = fopen('posts.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($fp, '');
chmod("posts.txt", 0644);

// you may have to use this one
// remember to comment out the one with 0644 if using this one
// chmod("posts.txt", 0777);
fclose($fp);
}

// check if "msg" is set
if(isset($_REQUEST['msg'])) {
$file = 'posts.txt';  
$str = $_POST['msg'] . "\n";
$temp = file_get_contents($file);
$content = $str.$temp;
file_put_contents($file, $content);

// echo success message
echo "Saved to $file successfully!";
echo "<br>";
echo "Previous messages:";
echo "<hr>";

// print out previous posts
$file = file_get_contents('posts.txt', true);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $file);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, '/') === false) {
        $line = htmlspecialchars($line . "\n");
        echo nl2br($line);
    }
}
exit;
} // end of if(isset($_REQUEST['msg']))

?>

<form id="post" name="post" action="" method="post">
<textarea name="msg" rows="5"></textarea>
<br>
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="POST!" />
</form>

<?php include 'display_div.php'; ?>
```

### display_div.php

**N.B.:** You can get rid of `Previous messages:<br>` or replace it with your text.

```
<div class="menuItem" >
Previous messages:<br>
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('posts.txt', true);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $file);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, '/') === false) {
        $line = htmlspecialchars($line . "\n");
        echo nl2br($line);
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Fred.  This has been helpful.  I didn't copy it exactly, but I am in the process of mimicking the logic.  In particular, I wanted to store and then print out a post line-by-line, so this has helped with that.  I appreciate it! PS- I got it to post to the same page, but I am enhancing it now.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be missing an input.Please see below

```
<form id="post" name="post" action="storeText.php" method="post">
<textarea name="msg" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="POST!"/>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Yep, I realize I accidentally put the textarea outside of the form.

Comment: It looks like the php is running, but I can't open my file.  Is that a security issue?